# How to load pdf pages one by one?

Tags: java, android, performance, pdf

In my app I want to load pdf file and show to user, some pdf file is over 20mb with many pages. Sometimes loading pdf take long time. So, I am wondering if there is possible to load page one by one,

Like load first page, then show to user while loading second page..

I am using this library :

```
'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2


public class FlyerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PDFView mPDFview;

    private String mStoreId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flyer);

        mPDFview = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.flyer_pdfView);
        showPdf(mStoreId);
    }

    private void showPdf(String storeId) {
        mReference.child(storeId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Store storeChain = dataSnapshot.getValue(Store.class);
                String pdfUrl = storeChain.getFlyerPDF().toString();

                ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                new RetrievePDFStream().execute(pdfUrl);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream>
    {
        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings)
        {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode()==200)
                {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {

            mPDFview.fromStream(inputStream).load();
            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }

}
```

Small size pdf files loads fine, but large size pdf, even 5mb with 10pages take some times to load.

Loading only one page didnt work either.. looks like this loads full pdf file then showing only one page.

```
mPDFview.fromStream(inputStream).pages(0).load();
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?